# Interchanging two textbox value by clicking a button Ionic(angular)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

How do I swap text in textbox 1 and textbox 2 using a button in Ionic

Answer (score 0):

```
    //add two ng-models for both textboxes

//Assign the values to variables

var txt1 = $scope.textbox1 ;
var txt2 = $scope.textbox2;

//swap the values 

$scope.textbox1 = txt2;
$scope.textbox2 = txt2;
```